# Why isn't my javascript-rendered navbar being crawled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, seo

My bootstrap navbar is loaded through a function call in $(document).ready. This function loads the navbar (in header.html) something like this:

```
function loadHeader(callback){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/resources/"+language+"/header.html",
        async: true,
        success: function (data) {
            $('body').append(data);

            if(callback){
                callback();
            }

        },
        dataType: 'html'
    });     
}
```

I've tried setting async=false, but the crawlers will still not pick up the links in the navbar (I've tried with fetch+render through Google search console, as well as through the crawler program Screaming Frog).

The strangest thing is that the navbar is loaded BEFORE several other dynamic page elements, which Google search console has no problem rendering.

Here is a preview of what my navbar (in header.html) looks like:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top index-nav">
    <div class="container" style="width:100%;">      
      <div class="navbrand">
        <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="/en/">
          <img class="homelogo" src="/logos/company-Logo.png"/>
        </a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li class="dropdown resourcesLI">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle mousePointer" data-toggle="dropdown">Resources</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li class="Link"><a href="/en/page_1.html">Page 1</a></li>                            
              <li class="Link"><a href="/en/page_2.html">Page 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Why aren't my navbar links being picked up by crawlers?

**Edit:** it should be noted that I'm very new to SEO

Answer (score 0):

Generally I've answered your question in other way in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38948082/6715875

But if I wana elaborate more for you, I would say to you in a briefly:
All contents which have been updated partially after that `DOM` loaded, won't be indexed by the search engine crawlers. In these case you can pick some soloutions up which I've mentioned in above link.

Regards.